# There is no host gpu appearing in the trace viewer of Tensorflow profiler

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I captured a profile by using the profiler of tensorflow as [described here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance_analysis#top_of_page). I found there is no host gpu in my captures. The screenshot of my capture as following:
[image]

Is there any guess about this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
For windows version of cuda

- Step 1: Copy cupti64_xxx.dll under "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA<version>\extras\CUPTI\libx64" into "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA<version>\bin".
- Step2: Then follow solution [described here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-ERR_NVGPUCTRPERM-permission-issue-performance-counters#SolnTag)

You may only need to do step2.